Referencing commands in l3keys latex3 expl3
Concerning my MWE below, I am trying to define subfunctions in my keys, which I can then access within \itemJ. Here, I am trying to pass 'Test' to the subfunction \wsBox and \wsLine respectively. I have tried to define the subfunctions as:
ws / b .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl { \wsBox{#1} } }
and then to:
\NewDocumentCommand{\wsBox}{m}{
    #1 \\
}

But I do not beleive that this is going through the subfunction. I think what is happening is:
Test in \exp_args:No \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl{Test} is printed literally and not passed through the subfunction. The #1 in the subfunction seems to be taken as b, as observed in the output.
Wanting to be able to:

Pass a variable through \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl', e.g. Test' as #1
Then use this variable in the subfunction, e.g. \wsBox{#1}.

Hope that makes sense.
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_harry_itemj_tl
\tl_new:N \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl {}

\keys_define:nn { harry / itemj }
  {
    opt .tl_set:N = \l_harry_itemj_options_tl,
    opt .initial:n = {},
    %
    ws .choice:,
    ws / b .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl { \wsBox{#1} } },
    ws / l .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl { \wsLine{#1} } },
    ws .default:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl {} }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{s O{} m O{}}
    {%
        \group_begin:    
        \keys_set:nn { harry / itemj } { #2 }
        \exp_args:NNNe
        \group_end:
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l_harry_itemj_tl
        {
            \exp_not:N 
                \task 
                    \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}
                    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_harry_itemj_options_tl
                        {}
                        {[\l_harry_itemj_options_tl]}
            \exp_not:n { #3 \\ }
            \exp_args:No \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl{Test}
            \exp_not:n {\textit{Solution:} ~ #4 }
        }
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\wsBox}{m}{
    #1 abcd \\
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\wsLine}{m}{
    #1 xyz \\
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{harrytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
  }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_harry_itemj_tl
  }
  {
    \harry_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_harry_itemj_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \harry_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harry_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{harrytasks}
  \itemJ[ws=b]{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}(2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ[opt={(X)}]{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}[label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}](2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\end{document}

Output:

Desired output:
a) First item
Test abcd
Solution: This is the solution
Where test is passed in as #1

what does 'not working' mean? do you get an error? if so, which? do you not get the output you want? if so, what needs to be different?

your code compiles without error and produces the output I'd expect. you have just put Print~something in the middle of the definition as-is, so it is just parsed in the regular way and output in the relevant place for each item. I assume that's not what you want to happen, but I'm struggling to figure out what you do want it to do.

Fair enough, let me edit the question. Apologies.

Have updated now. Not getting the output that I wanted. Hopefully made the desired outcome clearer!

As I said before, you need to read up on the syntax to understand what's going on. expl3 (tries) (sometimes, in some ways) to wear its meaning on its sleeve. If you read the syntax, you immediately have at least some idea of which things are likely to do what.
\exp_args:No \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl{Test} % !! NO

doesn't make sense. What do you want this to do?

\l_harry_itemj_ws_tl doesn't take an argument.
The _tl tells you what you have is a variable - a token list to be exact. It doesn't absorb an argument so whatever comes after it is just the next thing in the input stream.
\exp_args:No is intended for cases where you have a function and you want to expand something once before passing it to that function.

A function in expl3 looks like \harry_description:<argument specifier>. For example,
  \cs_new:Nn \harry_itemj_ws:n { #1 }
  \cs_new_protected:Nn \harray_itemj_wsx:n { #1 }

Both are functions. The first expands freely. The second is protected from expansion. The :n means the function takes a single braced argument, which is #1 in the function's defintion. Here, the function just spits its argument back out as-is.




This may be closer to what you want.

I don't see the point of \NewDocumentCommand here.

You need an internal function anyway if it is going to absorb an argument, so just set that directly.
You also (I think) need it to be expandable, which it won't be if defined with \NewDocumentCommand.
This does mean you have to protect anything problematic from expanding too early, but you're already doing that anyway.



I doubt this is the best way to do what you ultimately want to do, but I don't know what that is, so I don't know why it isn't1.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_harry_itemj_tl
\cs_new:Nn \harry_itemj_ws:n { #1 }

\keys_define:nn { harry / itemj }
{
  opt .tl_set:N = \l_harry_itemj_options_tl,
  opt .initial:n = {},
  %
  ws .choice:,
  ws / b .code:n = {
    \cs_set:Nn \harry_itemj_ws:n  { abcd \fbox{##1} \\ }
  },
  ws / l .code:n = {
    \cs_set:Nn \harry_itemj_ws:n { xyz \exp_not:n {\textbar} ##1 \exp_not:n {\textbar} \\ }
  },
  ws .default:n = { \cs_set:Nn \harry_itemj_ws:n {##1} }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{s O{} m O{}}
{%
  \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { harry / itemj } { #2 }
    \exp_args:NNNe
  \group_end:
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_harry_itemj_tl
  {
    \exp_not:N
    \task
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_harry_itemj_options_tl
    {[\l_harry_itemj_options_tl]}
    \exp_not:n { #3 \\ }
    \harry_itemj_ws:n { Test }
    \exp_not:n {\textit{Solution:} ~ #4 }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\wsBox}{m}{
  #1 abcd \\
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\wsLine}{m}{
  #1 xyz \\
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{harrytasks}
{
  O{} % optional options
  D(){1} % number of columns
}
{
  \tl_clear:N \l_harry_itemj_tl
}
{
  \harry_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_harry_itemj_tl
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \harry_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
{
  \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harry_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{harrytasks}
  \itemJ[ws=b]{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ[ws=l]{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}(2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ[opt={(X)}]{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}[label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}](2)
  \itemJ[ws=b]{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\end{document}

Edit
The default is defined as
ws .default:n = { \cs_set:Nn \harry_itemj_ws:n {##1} }

so it simply prints its argument. ##1 represents the argument. So,
ws .default:n = { \cs_set:Nn \harry_itemj_ws:n {} }

would simply discard that argument. The n in \harry_itemj_ws:n means it will still absorb the argument. The {} means it will do nothing with anything.
What you might want, though, is not this line but, rather,
\cs_new:Nn \harry_itemj_ws:n {}

at the top. a .default:n value is used only if the key is used without a value. It isn't used if the key isn't given at all. So if you want nothing printed if the key isn't used, change the \cs_new:Nn line instead (or as well).
1But didn't egreg already give you code that did something like this better?

Many thanks; great answer. Is there a way to turn off the default option from printing so that if neither b nor l are supplied nothing prints?

@Harry see edit.
